# Expressing LINQ .Single() statement is explicit NUnit Test

Tags: c#, nunit

I have the following test:

```
[Test]
public void ListContainsAnObjectOfTypeFoo()
{
    list.Single(t => t.GetType() == typeof(foo));
}
```

This "works" in the context that the test throws an exception and fails if an item of that type doesn't exist, or exists more than once.

Semantically however, it's not so nice. is there any way I could test that `Single()` condition stands using explicit NUnit Asserts? I wondered if perhaps there's a secret in `CollectionAssert` that I can't see.

Comment: How would you use an `Assert` when the code throws an exception? Why not try `SingleOrDefault` and check agains't `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this five years later, there's a much nicer solution in NUnit now!

```cs
Assert.That(list, Has.Exactly.One.TypeOf<foo>());
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Single`, get the count and compare it against `1` like:

```
list.Count(t => t.GetType() == typeof(foo)) ! = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.Count(condition)==1`

So, in your case use an assert with the condition:

```
list.Count(t => t.GetType() == typeof(foo)) == 1
```